# Cross-thread access exceptions: How to implement?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I noticed some frameworks throw an exception when you try to access objects or properties from a different thread than the main thread.

What is a suitable way to detect and throw an exception if my object (or a method in my object) is accessed from a different thread than the one that created it. Is there some notion of a thread "owning" an object?

Comment: What sort of exception does the frameworks throw and which are those frameworks?

Comment: You want to implement cross-thread exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The language and the libraries have no concept of threads "owning" any object.  You can implement it yourself easily enough:

```
class MyClass {
    final Thread owner;

    MyClass() {
        owner = Thread.currentThread();
    }

    void assertOwnership() {
        if (Thread.currentThread() != owner) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Current thread does not own: " + this);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:  But what problem are you really trying to solve?  One of the essential facts about threads is that they all operate in the same address space, and they all have equal access to the same data.  Why do you care which thread "owns" a given object?  What is the exception supposed to mean when one thread accesses an object that it doesn't "own?"

Comment: Some properties of the class are not thread safe while others are. An attempt to access a thread-unsafe property from a different thread should throw an exception.

Comment: That sounds like a use-case for mutual exclusion.  It does not sound like a reason why you should test "ownership".  If some thread, A, does not need to use some object, O, then it should never _try_ to access thread O.  Anything else is bad design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use thread local data to enforce this. The framework inserts thread local variable on the main thread.  When you invoke the framework it looks to see if the thread local variable exists.  If it doesn't then it throws an exception.

Look at the ThreadLocal class or [this tutorial](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-use-threadlocal-in-java-benefits.html)